# How to wrap email addresses to fit in fixed width box

Tags: ckeditor, zurb-foundation, block, html5boilerplate

I have a problem, see the image below:

[image: My bug. For security reasons I have blurred the telef numbers and e-mail addresses]

As you can see, the text is overflowing instead of breaking the text into a new line. My question is: How can I solve this issue?

The text is being inputted via CKEditor. I leave you with the code:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo $myData09 ?></legend>
        <div class="small-11 small-centered columns text-center margem_cima">
            <ul class="small-block-grid-3 text-left">
                <li><?php echo $myData10 ?></li>
                <li><?php echo $myData11 ?></li>
                <li><?php echo $myData12 ?></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email addresses are too long and won't wrap as is. You could replace the displayed email address with 'Email' and link it to their address using `mailto`.

Or you could use `word-wrap: break-word` or one of the options in [this article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/).

```
-ms-word-break: break-all; /* Be VERY careful with this, breaks normal words wh_erever */ 
word-break: break-all; /* Non standard for webkit */ 
word-break: break-word; 
-webkit-hyphens: auto; 
-moz-hyphens: auto; 
hyphens: auto;
```

Comment: Now that is something I did not know about. Thank you very much for that knowledge! I did solve the situation by typing personname [@] email.com and so it will remain because of your warning -ms-word-break: break-all; but I will definitely be watching over the evolution of this CSS rule. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. It'll be nice when these typography helpers are more standard.